# C# наследуемый метод работает с родительскими полями

Tags: c#, ооп, наследование

При наследовании, вызывая метод дочернего элемента AAA он продолжает работать с полями родительского класса BBB, а не дочернего. 
Как это исправить

Этот код работает как надо

```
public class AAA : BBB
{
    public new static string[] Titles =
    {
        "а","б", "в"
    };

    public new static int[] Indexs = new int[13];

     public static void A(string[] x)
    {
        Indexs[0] = Titles.Length;
    }
}

public class Excel
{
    public List<AAA> Профиль = new List<AAA>();
    ...
    AAA.A(titleRow);
}
```

А как сделать наследование, чтобы работало как в первом примере?

Т.е. код показанный ниже не работает

```
public class BBB
{
    public static string[] Titles;
    public static int[] Indexs;

    public static void A(string[] x)
    {
        Indexs[0] = Titles.Length;
    }
}

public class AAA : BBB
{
    public new static string[] Titles =
    {
        "а","б", "в"
    };

    public new static int[] Indexs = new int[13];
}

public class Excel
{
    public List<AAA> Профиль = new List<AAA>();
    ...
    AAA.A(titleRow);
}
```

Comment: хм, наследование и `static` это несовместимые вещи. Что вы пытаетесь сделать? Избавляйтесь от static

Comment: хочу в нескольких классах иметь одинаковый метод, но чтобы он работал с полями именно этих классов.
А эти поля нужны именно в static

Comment: Это нормально работает, для этого и есть ООП, но оно несовместимо со статикой, избавляйтесь от нее, просто создавайте экземпляр один раз и пользуйтесь им всегда (на крайняк синглтон напишите)

Comment: `А эти поля нужны именно в static` - почему такое условие?

Comment: потому что от этих классов будет множество объектов, но будут такие параметры. которые будут одинаковы для каждого объекта, поэтому нет смысла относить эти поля к объектам, а лучше отнести их к классу.

Comment: Может [Singleton](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) поможет?

Comment: `new` мне нужно, потому что в каждом дочернем от `BBB` классе у меня будут различные поля и мне нужны новые поля, которые я буду определять в дочерних классах, но нужен метод `A` родительского класс `BBB`, но чтобы он работал с новыми полями, дочерних классов

Comment: @ЮрийБезруков Что-то ты путаешься в показаниях... тебе нужно `поля нужны именно в static` потому что `параметры. которые будут одинаковы для каждого объекта` или ты все же  делаешь new `потому что в каждом дочернем от BBB классе у меня будут различные поля и мне нужны новые поля, которые я буду определять в дочерних классах` ? Определись точно что ты хочешь и опиши в вопросе корректно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Судя по всему, вы не понимаете что делает:

   ```
   public new static int[] Indexs = new int[13];
   ```

Поясню, эта строчка не перезаписывает поле Indexs в классе BBB. Эта строчка создаёт новое поле, с новым именем, и с новым адресом в памяти. Далее, ваш родительский метод, как и обращался к своему _BBB_Indexs полю, так и обращается, а то что вы ввели _AAA_Indexs - картину не изменило. Это РАЗНЫЕ поля.

2. Для решения данной задачи, вы должны использовать ООП. Вам надо избавиться от static, далее, у вас несколько способов решения проблемы.

**Вариант 1** - создать метод public int[] getIndexs(), определить его в BBB, и перезаписать его в AAA, при этом, остальной код в BBB обязан работать только с getIndexs(), и не лезть в поле напрямую. Так ваши new поля смогут быть перезаписаны (хотя, лично я не вижу в этом смысла... удобнее перезаписать сами методы, или изменить адрес значения полей у BBB, нежели создавать новые поля у ААА и переопределять родительские методы)

```
public class BBB
{
    public virtual string[] Titles { get; set; }
    public virtual int[] Indexs { get; set; }

    public BBB(string[] titles, int[] indexs) : base()
    {
        Titles = titles;
        Indexs = indexs;
    }

    public void A(string[] x)
    {
        Indexs[0] = Titles.Length;
    }
}

public class AAA : BBB
{
    public AAA() : base(new string[]{"а","б", "в"}, new int[13])
    {

    }

}

public class Excel
{
    public List<AAA> Профиль = new List<AAA>();
    ...
    AAA.A(titleRow);
}
```

**Вариант 2** - создать интерфейс, и определять методы по нему.

Comment: Аааа, что за getXXX/setXXX, это же не java! У нас есть полноценные свойства!

Comment: @Андрей, забыл, исправил)) Спасибо что заметили)

Comment: "вы не понимаете что" +1,  дальше не читал